# How to Debug error:1038, Severity 15, State: 4 when exec a SP from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

When I execute a Store Procedure from PHP

```
$days = 30;
$stmt = mssql_init('[dbo].[DEVDB_sp_GET_Overpayment_By_Provider]');
mssql_bind($stmt, '@Days', $days, SQLINT4);
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
mssql_free_statement($stmt);
$array = array();
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_NUM)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}
```

I get `error:1038, Severity 15, State: 4` in the SQL Profiler

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, 
>       verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias 
>       names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a 
>       valid name. (severity 15)

If I run this Sp from SQL, just run without any problem

This the [dbo].[DEVDB_sp_GET_Overpayment_By_Provider] Code

```sql
@FromDate DATE = NULL,
@ToDate DATE = NULL,
@Days INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        --Start : Calculate the from date and to date based on the specified days
        IF(@Days > 0 AND @FromDate IS NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL)
        BEGIN 
                SET @FromDate = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-@Days,GETDATE()))
                SET @ToDate = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
        END 
        --End

        --Start : Select top 5 providers with highest overpayment
        SELECT 
                        RES.ProvID,RES.ProvName,R_L.LOB,SUM(PPI.PIyAmt) AS [OverPAmt]
        FROM 
                        DBO.DEVDB_CH PCH 
                        INNER JOIN DBO.DEVDB_PIy PPI ON PCH.ClientCHID = PPI.ClientCHID
                        INNER JOIN (SELECT  TOP 5 
                                                                P_CH.ProvID,
                                                                P_PROV.ProvName
                                                FROM    
                                                                DBO.DEVDB_Prov P_PROV WITH(NOLOCK)
                                                                INNER JOIN DBO.DEVDB_CH P_CH WITH(NOLOCK) ON P_PROV.ProvID = P_CH.ProvID
                                                                INNER JOIN DBO.DEVDB_PIy  P_PI WITH(NOLOCK) ON P_CH.ClientCHID = P_PI.ClientCHID
                                                WHERE   
                                                                (P_PI.DatePROVNotified1st BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) AND
                                                                P_PI.PIyAmt > 0
                                                GROUP BY 
                                                                P_CH.ProvID,P_PROV.ProvName
                                                ORDER BY
                                                                SUM(P_PI.PIyAmt) DESC) AS [RES] ON PCH.ProvID = RES.ProvID
                        INNER JOIN DBO.REF_LOB_tbl R_L  ON PCH.LOBID = R_L.LOBID                    
        WHERE 
                        (PPI.DatePROVNotified1st BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) AND
                         PPI.PIyAmt > 0                     
        GROUP BY
                        R_L.LOB,RES.ProvID,RES.ProvName
        ORDER BY 
                        RES.ProvID
        --End
END
```

The result Set is

[image: Result set whe SP is execute from SQL]

How can I debug this kind of error.

I note each time I got this kind of error is when exist NULL Values

Comment: You need to show us the output of `$stmt`. None of us is going to know exactly what query `mssql_init` came up with.

Comment: Aye aye, seriously? I mean print the command instead of executing it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand sorry I dont undestand when you say print the command...could explain..sorry my bad english

Comment: Do you know how to output the contents of a variable to the browser in PHP? Do that with `$stmt` after you've received it from the `mssql_init` function instead of blindly executing it. This is how you debug.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Is this really happening. /unsubscribe

Comment: @EmilioGort what command does `$stmt` contains?

Comment: Someone please burninate this question with the power of 100,000 suns

Comment: @AaronBertrand what is the problem, why u said that? you should know stmt return Resource id #7, I executing a SP no an inline query

Comment: @EmilioGort Can you get (through SQL Server Management Studio) the whole code for `[dbo].[DEVDB_sp_GET_Overpayment_By_Provider]`?

Comment: @ypercube it's the sql I posted

Comment: Your issue may indeed be connected with passing NULL arguments. Perhaps you'll need to extend your knowledge of the [`mssql_bind` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php "PHP: mssql_bind - Manual") (please pay attention to the function's argument called `$is_null`) and then extend the call to it in your PHP.

Comment: @AndriyM good point...I note I got this kind of error when exist null values, but how to deal with that if I got the error just exec the the sp..you can guide me pls, I cant reach the mssql_fetch_array point

Comment: @AndriyM i tried `mssql_bind($stmt, '@Days', $days, SQLINT4,FALSE,FALSE);` or `mssql_bind($stmt, '@Days', $days, SQLINT4,FALSE,TRUE);` I get the same error

Comment: Your procedure appears to have other parameters too, and you aren't setting values (or NULLs) to them in your code.

Comment: @AndriyM `IF(@Days > 0 AND @FromDate IS NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL)` this should be no problem for that...I will check anyway adding the other parameters?

Comment: if you post as answer I will accept and upvote it...super grateful

Comment: @ypercube thankyou you too for you time, very apreciate

Comment: Thank you but I am not even a PHP amateur, let alone expert, I wouldn't be able to explain why binding the other two parameters explicitly was necessary. (And I would hate posting an answer saying just "Do this" without explaining why where that is not obvious, especially if I myself don't understand that.) You, on the other hand, could post your own answer to just show what you ended up with, and some [PHP+SQL Server] expert passing by later might grace you with a nice authoritative explanation of the issue. Even if not, you'd at least be able to accept your own answer and close the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44466/discussion-between-emilio-gort-and-andriy-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved binding the other two SQL parameter and specifying `is_null` parameter in
[mssql_bind](https://www.php.net/mssql_bind)

```
$days= 30;
$FromDate = NULL;
$ToDate = NULL;
mssql_bind($stmt, '@Days', $days, SQLINT4,FALSE,FALSE);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@FromDate ', $FromDate , SQLVARCHAR,FALSE,TRUE);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ToDate', $ToDate, SQLVARCHAR,FALSE,TRUE);
```

I don't know why I have to bind the other two parameters if in the SQL I have

`IF(@Days > 0 AND @FromDate IS NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL)`

But it works, would be nice someone with the knowledge explain in more details this topic.

Special Thanks to @AndriyM and @ypercube for guide trough the process.